# Combine the list of element in compound form

Tags: python

I have combination in the form

```
[(a,b,c), (b,a,c), (c,a,b)]
```

I want to write them as:

```
[abc,bac, cab]
```

Kindly suggest the code to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

This code is using the `join()` method and list comprehension.

```py
my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b')]
print([''.join(each_tuple) for each_tuple in my_list])
```

You can use for-loop instead of list comprension.

```py
my_list = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b')]
new_list = list()
for each_tuple in my_list:
    new_list.append(''.join(each_tuple))

print(new_list)
```

Further resources:

- `join()`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp
- List Comprehension: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That's a good point. I tried to improve the quality of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

a,b,c are string, int, objects?

```py
    array = [('a','b','c'), ('b','a','c'), ('c','a','b')]
    array = [''.join(x) for x in array]
```

this should work with strings

Answer (score 0):

Just use Python `join` function:

```
list(map(''.join, x))
```